# Why I don't have permissions to remove six while installing a pip package?

Tags: python, installation, pip, tensorflow

I've run this command to pip install TensorFlow:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I'm having trouble removing six (to reinstall it anyway?)

Does anyone have any insight into this problem. `pip uninstall six` doesn't work either

my terminal is spitting out:

```
Collecting tensorflow==0.5.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==0.5.0)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.9.2 (from tensorflow==0.5.0)
Installing collected packages: six, numpy, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: six 1.9.0
    Uninstalling six-1.9.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Comment: Try putting a `sudo` in front of the command.

Comment: Thanks! Every time I see "Permission Denied" I will now know what could be the issue!

Comment: @Alex if I use sudo infront of command "pip install something" will the package be installed in my virtual-environment or the root environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your `pip` is `python2.x` for the **location** field:

```
$ pip show pip
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pip
Version: 7.1.2
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

Then:

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```